# Why do I have to call GraphicsEnvorinment.registerFont() even if I my Font were created from file?

Tags: java, fonts, awt, jfreechart

I'm developing a web application which use JFreeChart to render chart. However, when server dose not have any Chinese font installed, JFreeChart dose not display Chinese character even if I have set the font.

Then I write a small testing code and find out that add this line of code before drawing the chart can solve the problem.

```
GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().registerFont(font);
```

So my questions are -

1. **Why do I have to register font into JVM even if I create my font from File?** Does that mean JFreeChart do not use the font I set directly?
2. When I deploy my program into server, even if I add this line of code, it dose not display Chinese characters. **How do I make it always use the font I set in order to display character properly in all environment?**

I know I can make a `fallback` directory in `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib` and put my font into it. But that dose not explain why JFreeChart cannot display with the font I set.

## UPDATE

I'm pretty sure the font were load correctly, and so does `registerFont()` return true when I deploy the program into Tomcat.

## UPDATE 2

According to [JAVA 2D FAQ](http://java.sun.com/products/java-media/2D/reference/faqs/index.html#Q_How_can_I_make_my_custom_font), now I realize I have to call `registerFont()` in order to make my own font "installed" into JVM, and my font will be available through `Font` constructor.

> As of Java SE 6, there is a method :
> GraphicsEnvironment.registerFont() which gives you the ability to make
> a "created" font available to Font constructors and to be listed via
> Font enumeration APIs. Font.createFont() and this method combine to
> provide a way to "install" a Font into the running JRE so it is
> available just as O/S installed fonts are. However this Font does not
> persist across JRE invocations.

But, since I already have `Font` instances created/derived from `createFont()`, why doesn't my program still need to create other `Font`?

---

Following is the code I used, it simply output a chart in PNG format. If you want to run the code, you should change the output location and font to fit your need, and [here is the SourceForge link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wqy/files/wqy-zenhei/0.9.45%20%28Fighting-state%20RC1%29/) for Chinese font I use in code.

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.io.File;

import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartUtilities;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.StandardChartTheme;
import org.jfree.data.general.DefaultPieDataset;
import org.jfree.data.general.PieDataset;

public class Problem {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    setJFreeChartTheme();

    PieDataset dataset = createDataSet();
    JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createPieChart(
        "Chinese Testing", dataset, true, true, false);
    ChartUtilities.saveChartAsJPEG(new File("/tmp/output.png"), 
        chart, 800, 600);

    System.out.println("Done");
  }

  private static void setJFreeChartTheme() throws Exception {
    Font font = loadFont();
    //==================================================================
    GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().registerFont(font);
    //==================================================================
    StandardChartTheme theme = new StandardChartTheme("Chinese font", true);
    theme.setExtraLargeFont(font.deriveFont(Font.BOLD, 20));
    theme.setLargeFont(font.deriveFont(Font.BOLD, 16));
    theme.setRegularFont(font.deriveFont(Font.PLAIN, 14));
    theme.setSmallFont(font.deriveFont(Font.PLAIN, 12));
    ChartFactory.setChartTheme(theme);
  }

  private static Font loadFont() throws Exception {
    File file = new File("/tmp/wqy-zenhei.ttc");
    return Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, file);
  }

  private static PieDataset createDataSet() {
    DefaultPieDataset dataset = new DefaultPieDataset();
    dataset.setValue("種類1", Integer.valueOf(1));
    dataset.setValue("種類2", Integer.valueOf(2));
    dataset.setValue("種類3", Integer.valueOf(3));
    return dataset;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create a `Font` directly from the TTF, Java obviously knows where to get a copy of the font file itself from within that single Font object. So why does the font also need to be registered in order to use it? **The answer is that it does not always have to be registered**, or at least not so long as the entire chain of control uses the original `Font` object directly.

### What really happens when Java tries to render the font?

The nuance is in how JFreeChart asks to render the text. Rendering of text is performed in the `TextUtilities#drawRotatedString` method from jcommon. On JDK7, this method will, by default:

- create an `AttributedString` based on the "attributes" of the font that you have passed in,
- call `Graphics2D#drawString` on the attributed string, which then
- creates a new `TextLayout` object.

`TextLayout` is the class that selects the actual Font object to be provided to `Graphics2D`. `TextLayout` is designed to support the rendering of multilingual text using various fonts (even if the same single source String needs to be rendered in multiple fonts) by using automatic font selection to find an appropriate font for each piece of the string.

The "attributes" mentioned above are simple facts about the font (like font family name, size, etc) that are derived from the `Font` that you provide. In the event that the font you've provided is unable to render all of the characters in the input string, the attributes are used to select similar fonts to use for those runs of text that need to use a different font.

When JFreeChart invokes TextLayout, it always functions like this:

- extract the attributes from the `Font` object you supplied,
- call the *static* `Font#getFont` to get a font that matches the supplied attributes (see `TextLayout#singleFont`), and
- uses the returned (possibly different) Font object to draw the text.

If you have not *statically* registered your font somewhere (like with `GraphicsEnvironment#registerFont`), then all that the *static* `Font#getFont` method will have to go on is the attribute string containing the font family name. It won't know where to access the Font object that contains the reference to the TTF, let alone any of the data needed to actually render the font.

## OK, but I thought you said that I didn't need to register the font?

If you don't want to register the font, then the trick is in making sure that your text is rendered only with the `Font` object that you provide. It so happens that there is another constructor for `TextLayout` that accepts a `Font` object directly, rather than a set of attributes that are used to look up a font.

Helpfully, JFreeChart even provides a way to force it to use this constructor instead. In `TextUtilities#drawRotatedString`, a special configuration parameter can be used to force JFreeChart to construct the `TextLayout` object itself using the exact `Font` object you provide.

To do this, you can either set up a jcommon.properties file like this:

- create a resource file named `jcommon.properties` (which should end up in the root level of your classpath/JAR), and
- add the following line to it:

`org.jfree.text.UseDrawRotatedStringWorkaround=true`

or else simply make a call to the static function:

```
TextUtilities.setUseDrawRotatedStringWorkaround(true)
```

This will ask JFreeChart to render the text using your font directly, and...**voila! It works even without having registered the font**. This was tested in the context of the question above, which is that of using JFreeChart to render the text directly to a raster image. Your mileage might vary if you are trying to render to a display device (which I did not try).

## Is it wise not to register the font?

I can't say for sure. One of my applications runs inside an OSGi container and I was wary of creating PermGen classloader leaks by statically registering a Font that can never be unregistered. Using the Font object directly avoids that problem, which is why I wanted to go this route. I suppose it's always possible that a specific Java platform might have trouble if you did this, but this works fine in my tests on at least Windows, Linux, and OS X hosts with Oracle JDK 7.

Answer (score 1):

> Why do I have to register font into JVM even if I create my font from file?

How else is the JVM going to know your font exists?

Your font has to be registered with the JVM so that Java knows how to draw your font in the graphics environment that JFreeChart uses to render charts.

> How do I make it always use the font I set in order to display character properly in all environment ?

You need to check that the `registerFont()` method returns true.  If it returns false, your font is not available.

It looks like you're loading the font correctly.  Maybe the file path of your font isn't correct on your server.  You might want to try

```
getClass().getResource(fontPath);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you explain more about the register part ? Since I'm not using font name to construct `Font`, why dose JVM need to check if the font exist ?

Comment: By the way.`registerFont()` return true.

Comment: @RangiLin: So the font can be drawn using the Graphics class.  See my updated answer.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the update, now I realize what registerFont() is for (see my **UPDATE2**). But I still don't understand why my program have to create another `Font` instance from constructor, since I already pass one into it. Is that somekind of bug ? or is there any different between those two `Font` ?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I was searching for the answer myself and having seen the responses above, I still didn't really understand the purpose of registering a font. Having researched the issue, this is what I found:

You don't have to register your font with the graphics environment, but doing so comes with the advantage of being able to use the registered font in 'new Font()' constructors.

You can use the following code to get a list of all the fonts which are currently available (i.e installed and ready to use in your application):

```
String fonts[] = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getAvailableFontFamilyNames();
```

Assuming you're on Windows, and one of the installed fonts is Arial, you can use this font in your application like this:

```
JButton yesButton = new JButton ("Yes");
yesButton.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN,30));
```

Now Suppose you want to load in and use your own custom font from a file:

```
Font robotoFont = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT,getClass().getResourceAsStream("/res/fonts/Roboto/Roboto-Light.ttf"));
```

If you wanted to set that as the font for a JButton, you might write this code:

```
JButton yesButton = new JButton("Yes");
yesButton.setFont(robotoFont.deriveFont(Font.PLAIN, 30f));
```

But if you tried to write some code like:

```
JButton yesButton = new JButton("Yes");
yesButton.setFont(new Font ("Roboto Light", Font.PLAIN,30));
```

The JButton would just be given a default font, because the graphics environment is not aware of any font named "Roboto Light". The solution to this is to *register your font with the graphics environment* :

```
 GraphicsEnvironment genv = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
 genv.registerFont(robotoFont);
```

You will then be able to use this font in 'new Font()' constructors like this:

```
JButton yesButton = new JButton("Yes");
bestButton.setFont(new Font ("Roboto Light", Font.PLAIN,30));
```