# setFont() causing JFrame loading too slow , java

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, fonts

I need your help for this issue....
     I have a JFrame that has setFont(font) function on some of its components. The setFont function causes the JFrame loading too slow.  Is there any substitute for it.or should I import fonts in the java package or something????.

```
Font userTextFont=new Font("Joy",Font.BOLD,15);
userText.setFont(userTextFont);
```

It loads good if I remove

```
userText.setFont(userTextFont);
```

userText is a JTextField...

The Short Code (with similar problem):-

```
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class fonttest{

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {

      fonttest f1=new fonttest();
      f1.go();
  }
     public void go()
   {
      JFrame frame=new JFrame();

      JTextField userTextField=new JTextField(40);
      Font font=new Font("Impact",Font.BOLD,16);
      userTextField.setFont(font);

      frame.getContentPane().add(userTextField);
      frame.setVisible(true);
      frame.setSize(100,100);

   }

}
```

Comment: Keep just one `userTextFont`, as JFrame field. Look whether 14 or 16 is not faster. You could also try [loading the font file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12112353/why-do-i-have-to-call-graphicsenvorinment-registerfont-even-if-i-my-font-were) explicitly stored in your application as resource.

Comment: post a (SSCCE)[www.sscce.org], post where you initializes all this stuff

Comment: Also look at `deriveFont()`.

Comment: 14 or 16 doesn't make it faster sir.....

Comment: I posted a SSCCE ...please see

Comment: works perfect with me. What do you consider 'loading to slow'?
you should use SwingUtilities.invokeLater when using the swing library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem of the components being "slow" to load is that they are not validated yet. The `Window` [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setVisible%28boolean%29) for `setVisible` method says:

> If the Window and/or its owner are not yet displayable, both are made displayable. The Window will be validated prior to being made visible.

When you call `setVisible()`, all the components need to be validated. You can validate them before calling `setVisible()` calling `pack()` on the `JFrame`:

```
  frame.getContentPane().add(userTextField);
  frame.pack();
  frame.setSize(100,100);
  frame.setVisible(true);
```