# Why the same font looks different in Java app run from Netbeans and run from Jar?

Tags: java, swing, fonts, look-and-feel

In my Java Swing app I have some JTextAreas, I realize the text looks different when it's run from Netbeans and when the app is run from a Jar file, why ? How to make them look the same ?

```
JTextArea Client_Side_TextArea=new JTextArea(),Network_TextArea=new JTextArea();

setLayout(new BorderLayout());

Client_Side_TextArea.setFont(new Font("Monospaced",0,15));
Client_Side_TextArea.setForeground(new Color(0,28,218));
Client_Side_TextArea.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(290,300));
Client_Side_TextArea.append("           Client Side\n================================\n");
add("West",Client_Side_TextArea);

Network_TextArea.setFont(new Font("Monospaced",0,15));
Network_TextArea.setBackground(new Color(226,226,226));
Network_TextArea.setForeground(new Color(0,28,218));
Network_TextArea.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(270,300));
Network_TextArea.append("            Network Connection\n =========================================\n");
add("Center",Network_TextArea);
```

In the following image, the upper part is from the app run with Netbeans, the lower part is how it looks when run from a Jar file :

[image]

Comment: Can you try     System.setProperty("sun.java2d.noddraw", "true"); at the end?

Comment: I tried it, didn't work, I also tried : System.setProperty("sun.java2d.d3d", "false"); didn't work either.

Comment: Can you set window size and set resizeable off?

Comment: I set : frame.setResizable(false); didn't work. Why it got different fonts ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the expected behavior: as discussed in the [`Font`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html) API, each supported platform may map a different *physical* font to a particulate *logical* font such as `Font.MONOSPACED`. Each [look & feel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html) may further refine the choice of font for a particular purpose. Unless the platforms, versions and settings are identical, the fonts may vary. A complete example and more on the mapping may be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26090878/230513).

In addition, for the reasons cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/230513), don't use `setPreferredSize()`. If you choose to override `getPreferredSize()`, be certain not to fall into this [trap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12532237/230513).