# How to add a custom font family to FlatLaf for a Java Swing application

Tags: java, swing, font-family, flatlaf

I'm trying to change the Font Family with FlatLaf for a Java Swing application.
It would be cool to find a way to change it in the customized theme files (`mytheme.properties`) for FlatLaf. I saw on the FlatLaf docs that its possible to specify font families.

From FlatLaf doc:

> family[, family ...] specify one or more font families. If a family is
> not available, then the next family is used. If none of the families
> are available, the family of the default/base font is used. If a
> family name contains spaces, enclose it in " or '.

Example:

> defaultFont = 13 "Open Sans", "Noto Sans", Roboto, Arial

I want to download a font family, add the `.ttf` file to my project, and specify the font family via the `.properties` file of FlatLaf.

Comment: What do you mean by "need to be added to the project first"? Do you want to have the font files themselves coming with your app? So that the users don't have to download them?

Comment: @GhostCat yes, I want to download the font family and add the ttf files to the project and specify the font family via the .properties file of FlatLaf.

Comment: Please dont add more information in comments, always edit your question instead. Dont expect your readers to dig through comments to get a clear understanding of your request.

Comment: You can use [`GraphicsEnvironment.registerFont`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/GraphicsEnvironment.html#registerFont(java.awt.Font)) to make any font loaded via `Font.createFont` available to your UI. So as long as you load it (however you want) before the PlaF tries to use it, that should be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I set the default font of my Maven project to Poppins Black, based on the comment by Joachim.

I placed my downloaded font file `Poppins-Black.ttf` inside `resources/font` folder. Maven will look for my font inside the [`resources`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/resource-directory.html) folder.

Then, I loaded my  `Poppins-Black.ttf` file and then I registered it as a font:

```java
File font_file = new File(this.getClass().getResource("/font/Poppins/Poppins-Black.ttf").getPath());
Black = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, font_file);  
GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().registerFont(Black);
```

**Important note:**

- If you are not using Maven your method of loading the font file might be slightly different.
- The above piece of code must be executed **before setting up the look and feel of your application**.

In my [`.properties`](https://www.formdev.com/flatlaf/properties-files/) file, I can now use `"Poppins Black"` to refer to the new font:

```
defaultFont = 18 "Poppins Black"
```

Now the default font of my application will be set to Poppins Black.

### References

- [Why do I have to call GraphicsEnvorinment.registerFont() even if I my Font were created from file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12112353/17627866)
- https://www.formdev.com/flatlaf/typography/